# Socket.io сервер, 100% CPU

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Код:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  log(`Client connected`, 'event');

  socket.on('kill', (id, callback) => {
    bots[id].kill('SIGHUP');

    callback && callback();
  });

  socket.on('cmd', cmd => {
    if(cmd.botID) bots[cmd.botID].send(cmd);
    else eval(cmd);
  });

  socket.on('bash', (cmd, callback) => {
    cp.exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if(err) log(`Socket bash exec error: ${err}`, 'error');

      callback(err || stdout);
    });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    log(`Client disconnected`, 'event');
  });
});
```

Появляется 100% нагрузка на ядра когда клиент закрывает соединение, помогает только перезапуск скрипта.

Comment: Откройте htop и посмотрите, что именно грузит систему - ваши боты или nodejs.

Comment: Вы на полном выполняете всё, что придёт из сокета `eval(cmd)`? Мало того, что eval медленный, так это ещё и чистейшая уязвимость.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, доступ к серверу разрешён только определённым IP-адресам. Нагрузка появляется когда закрываю определённую страницу в браузере с этим сокетом, если создать чистый клиент и не ставить на него события то нагрузки не будет.

Comment: Ну судя по коду выше ничего экстраординарного вы не делаете. Попробуйте подебажить ноду инспектором.